# Epplus to check if row in excel worksheet with in specified datarange or total sheet, is empty

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Working on a c# project which reads Excel worksheet and inserts values in to a table in database. There are few columns which can not be null , currently throwing an exception if that kind of value is null, but now need to handle with rows in excel file which are completely empty, so need to ignore that kind of rows, Epplus is being used, so need a way to check if row is empty and then delete it or ignore.

Comment: It sound like you import data directly from an Excel to the Database without any validation whatsoever. Make a layer in between that reads a row from Excel, validate the values in each cell and if all is well then save it to the DB.

Comment: Actually that is true, we got a validation layer which deals with xml data , but  we are doing Excel validations within the place we have Read(), but the issue will be reading each cell,one time at validation and again at Read(), else we can have a method from validation layer that  does ValidateCurrentCell value. I didn't find any Epplus method which can directly  find empty rows. Socurrent cell valu what I did is throw an exception once we find empty cell and then check all the columns in that row, if every thing  is empty just continue.